# Is there a good place to start selling my designs?

Tags: resource-recommendations, business

Good day all.

My question is quite simple, I've been making designs for many years, I have a good library of designs, but most of them were unused due to the fact that when a client ask me a design I always proposed at least 3 solutions.

Now I'm full of designs that will never been used and I would like to give them some use.

My idea is to modify them, give them a slight new appearance and sell on them to online marketplaces around the web, **like Envato**.

Is anyone else here  selling their designs online too? is there a good place to start, have you got some advice on it?

UPDATE: 
the designs are mostly website templates, logos, there are some specific elements like comparison charts, or users profile pages. But consider all are webdesign elements, usable by webmasters to design or complete websites.
I would like to send the entire PSD, fonts, and in some cases also some sripts (for dropdowns for example).
Non of theme are CMS templates, all should be used as base for website designs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are dozens upon dozens of options...most easily finable via google.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at Graphic River, this is the design part of Code Canyon that is run by Envato. That would be a good start!

[Link to Graphic River](http://graphicriver.net/)

In order to start selling on the marketplace you will need to read the terms and unless it has changed in the last 2 years, there is a few questions you need to get correct in order to be accepted. These include creative commons rules etc, to avoid forging and plagiarism.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I've mentioned it in my question due to the fact that is the only place i've found yet. Graphic river is a very professional place, and I would like to find places like this one, like the envato network... any other ideas?

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' You can try reading this article on best places to sell your designs. Some of the links may be of use: [link](http://mashable.com/2009/02/28/sell-designs-online/)

Answer (score -1):

CreativeMarket.com is my favourite

Comment: Hi user43616, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your input. Could you please tell us *why* this site is your solution? We like well-grounded answers here that show us the *why*, so we can objetively determine what answers are 'right'. If you want to know more about the site, have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!